# Error thrown when using to_sql to write pandas df to mysql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql, praw

I'm scraping reddit using praw and storing records in a pandas df. Using a combination of sqlalchemy & pymysql to connect to my AWS RDS db and to_sql to append records to an existing table. All seems to be working fine until I hit the to_sql method. It throws the following errors and i'm not really sure where to go from here. Any help or suggestions would be awesome!

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@database...rds.amazonaws.com:3306/socialdata')
df_comment = pd.DataFrame(comment_table)

df_comment.to_sql(name='reddit_comments', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ty/Desktop/Python/reddit_scraper.py", line 121, in <module>
    df_comment.to_sql(name='reddit_comments', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2605, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 589, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1398, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 830, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 747, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1514, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1256, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 148, in do_executemany
    rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 188, in executemany
    return self._do_execute_many(q_prefix, q_values, q_postfix, args,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 206, in _do_execute_many
    v = values % escape(next(args), conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 120, in _escape_args
    return {key: conn.literal(val) for (key, val) in args.items()}
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 120, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: conn.literal(val) for (key, val) in args.items()}
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 469, in literal
    return self.escape(obj, self.encoders)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 462, in escape
    return converters.escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 27, in escape_item
    val = encoder(val, mapping)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 123, in escape_unicode
    return u"'%s'" % _escape_unicode(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 78, in _escape_unicode
    return value.translate(_escape_table)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/base.py", line 35, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self, attribute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/base.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'Redditor' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the columns in your DataFrame contains a custom "Redditor" object which doesn't map to a corresponding SQL datatype. pymysql calls the object's translate function when it isn't something obvious like int float or string

If Redditor is just a wrapper object for a store of usernames and other metadata, then you can do something like remapping that column to the string / number representation of the Redditor object. If it is an object you've defined, you can add a translate() function to the Redditor class's definition to return the appropriate value. For example if Redditor.id contains the value that you want to store in the column :-

```
class Redditor():
  def translate(self):
    # Change self.id with the value you care about
    return self.id
```

or in pandas before you save

`df[REDDITOR_COLUMN] = df[REDDITOR_COLUMN].apply(lambda x: x.id)`

Comment: hey you're absolutely right I got ahead of myself for a second without checking, editing the post accordingly, thanks!